# how to get a collection to the query made ​​in windows azure?

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have a table called Activity (Mobile service), and i add a query in reading:

Azure Script:

```
function read(query, user, request) 
{
  var param = request.parameters.UserLocation;
  if(param)
  {
     var sql = "Select TOP 10 [NewsItemUrl], count(1) as CounterNews FROM [MobileServiceExtra].[ACTIVITY] WHERE [UserLocation] = ? GROUP BY [NewsItemUrl] ORDER BY CounterNews Desc";

     mssql.query(sql,param, {success: function(results) {request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results);}}); 
  }

//request.execute();
}
```

Client side:

```
 public class ACTIVITY
 {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserLocation")] 
        public string _UserLocation { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewsItemUrl")] 
        public string _NewsItemUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewsItemTitle")] 
        public string _NewsItemTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewsItemPublisher")] 
        public string _NewsItemPublisher { get; set; }

 }
```

If I do the query in sql, I get 2 columns CounterNews and NewsItemUrl and where the Last is the number of times to repeat the url. However, I dont know how to get the data in column "CounterNews", i mean,  when i want to get the query, i get to do with the Activity table (class) and obviously returns me the data correctly, but only NewsItemUrl column and the other fields are empty.

Client side:

```
 private MobileServiceCollection<ACTIVITY, ACTIVITY> TopReadCollectionActivity;

 private IMobileServiceTable<ACTIVITY> ACTIVITYTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<ACTIVITY>();

 private async void LoadTop10()
 {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "UserLocation", "United States" },
        };

        try
        {
            TopReadCollectionActivity = await ACTIVITYTable.WithParameters(dict).ToCollectionAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string err = ex.Message;
        }

 }
```

if i create a class (table too)"Top10", azure give a error, because the table doen't exist. and 
not want to create a new table.
how to get the query only two fields CounterNews and NewsItemUrl?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should just query the table directly using the OData support.  This way your not confined to the structure of your table.  Take a look at this for reference.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj677199.aspx